# GraphQL, How handle connecting to hundreds of Tables

Tags: database-design, graphql

We are implementing GraphQL and have hundreds of database tables we will need to pull data from.

We want to manage our API in such a way that its easy to traverse and data is broken up into logical groups.

Is there a way to implement something like this:

```
Group1> Queries
        Mutations
        Subscriptions
Group2> Queries
        Mutations
        Subscriptions
...
```

Or will we need to make separate endpoints for each GraphQL grouping of data?

Comment: The short answer is no, GraphQL doesn't provide a mechanism for doing something like that. There are only 3 root types and they cannot be abstract types like a Union or Interface. What is the goal you're trying to achieve by creating groups of operations like this? Are you serving different types of clients, with each needing a different set of operations?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DanielRearden. We have three main user groups and hundreds of tables. So we don't want to have 2X hundreds of Queries and 3X hundreds of Mutations, all showing at once. We would like to be able to group the data. So we may just need to create three different routes.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a question of aesthetics, I wouldn't really worry about the number of fields on your `Query` or `Mutation` types. Whether your client teams use [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) and [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground) to compose their queries (and they really should be using one of those tools), both have auto-completion features that make it simple to pick a specific field from a list of hundreds.

You may be working with specific groups of clients that have specific needs in terms of the data that's visible to them, or in terms of the types of mutations they can perform on the underlying data. In these cases, it may make sense to have separate endpoints with separate schemas, each limited to what a particular group of clients can see and do. If you're using Apollo, you can even start with a base schema and then utilize [schema transforms](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms.html). However, you probably shouldn't create separate endpoints if a particular client is just going to make queries against each endpoint anyway -- that places an undue burden on the client.

You can, of course, simply nest your fields for each root type inside other types. For example:

```
type Query {
  group1: Group1
  group2: Group2
}

type Group1 {
  foo: Foo
  allFoos: [Foo!]!
  # other fields
}

type Group2 {
  bar: Bar
  allBars: [Bar!]!
  # other fields
}
```

This is perfectly fine for your Query type, although I would [caution against this kind pattern for mutations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459947/are-mutation-methods-required-to-be-on-the-top-level/54463837#54463837). Of course, if you understand the implications, it may be the right solution for your team.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The problem is that I will potentially have hundreds of types, the fields on the types is not an issue but rather the number of types, and then the naming of them will start to get obscure requiring a glossary just to know what each type is.

There are basically three classes of data I have, so I could break it up into three routes. So that's what I'm probably going to have to do. I was hoping I could break it up within GraphQL so that devs could drill down into the three areas.

Comment: This video from Trulia devs at the GraphQL Summit suggests that they handled their areas by prefixing a "namespace" to their types - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUrtRzqN0h0&t=755