# Why the signup and me are always in the mutation and query types?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I'm learning GraphQL, and in EVERY example that I saw, the `signup`/`login` and `me` calls are in the `mutation` and `query` types. Why is that? Example:

```
type Query {
  me: User
}

type Mutation {
  login(email: String!, password: String!): String
}
```

Shouldn't this be in the `User` type? Since it's a user related thing?

I apologize if this is an opinion based question - and I will close the question if that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Language.Operations):

> There are three types of operations that GraphQL models:
>
> - query – a read‐only fetch.
> - mutation – a write followed by a fetch.
> - subscription – a long‐lived request that fetches data in response to source events.

Each operation is associated to a particular type, although both the mutation and subscription types are optional. So a schema might be defined like so:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}
```

Here, `Query` refers to a type named `Query`. By convention, the three types are named `Query`, `Mutation` and `Subscription` -- but they could be named anything else, it doesn't really matter. They do, however, have to be object types and must include at least one field.

**These operation types serve as the "root" of a GraphQL operation and are effectively the entry points to your data graph. No other types are exposed at the root level, even if they exist within your schema.**

A `me` or `viewer` field is often exposed on the `Query` type in order to allow users to fetched the currently logged in user. Assuming we already have a `User` type defined, if we add a `me` field to our `Query` type, and set the type for that field to `User`, we enable the consumers of our endpoint to write a query like:

```
query {
  me {
    # some set of User fields like id, firstName, etc.
  }
}
```

If we put the `me` field on the `User` type instead, a) we would not necessarily have a way to request the field, since it would not be at the root, and b) we would expose a `me` field everywhere we return a `User` (for example, a `friends` field that returns a List of `Users`) which doesn't make much sense.

The same logic applies for mutations like `login` -- we want them at the root of our operation, so we place them inside the `Mutation` type. Whether `login` should be a mutation or a query, on the other hand, [is subjective and depends on your particular use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql/50190570#50190570).

#### Quick aside around mutations:

If you're used to working with REST, it's common to see operations prefixed with the data sources they are operating on, for example:

```
POST /articles/{id}/bookmark
```

And we might be inclined to enforce a similar structure with our mutations, leading to requests like:

```
mutation {
  article {
    bookmark
  }
}
```

However, this is totally unnecessary, and in fact breaks convention and makes implementation more complicated. It's sufficient to instead do:

```
mutation {
  bookmarkArticle
}
```

More on this point can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459947/are-mutation-methods-required-to-be-on-the-top-level/54463837#54463837).

Answer (score 0):

This question based on GraphQL schema design. The design is 100% opinion based thing. But let me try answer on your question.

In `login` mutation answer, client should receives auth token or similar. This `token` will be send as http header every request for auth. Obviously, this `token` is not part of `User` entity. In complicated application you can design mutation answer like that:

```
{
  user: ...
  token: ...
}
```

But for demo application need only token (string) as `login` mutation answer.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be two separate questions.

The first answer here is, if you're making a GraphQL query, you need some way to get objects to start querying.  There's not a concept of "static methods" like you might see in Java or other object-oriented languages; these set of initial queries have to be on the root `Query` type.  You could imagine

```graphql
type Query {
  "The currently logged-in user."
  me: User!

  "Find a user by their email address."
  user(email: String!): User
}
```

You could query other fields on the `User` object once you have it, but you need some way to get it initially.

```graphql
query WhatsMyEmail {
  me { email }
}
```

Secondly, all operations that change data are top-level fields on the `Mutation` type.  This is mostly convention – nothing *actually* stops you from doing whatever you want in your resolver functions – but it has a couple of key impacts.  It's easy enough to just query every field on an object and to generate a query like that from the schema:

```graphql
fragment AllUserFields on User {
  id, name, email, delete
}
query WhoAmI {
  me { ...AllUserFields } # oops I deleted myself
}
```

You also have a guarantee that top-level mutations execute in order, but everything else in GraphQL can execute in any order.  If your schema allowed this, the `email` could be either the old or new email address, for example:

```
query ChangeMyEmail {
  me {
    changeEmail(email: "new@example.com")
    email  # is allowed to evaluate first and return old@example.com
  }
}
```

Things like "login" that really are just "actions" that aren't tied to any specific object make more sense to just be attached to `Mutation` and not any more specific type.  (If "login" were a property of `User`, which one, and how do you find it without already being logged in?)