# graphql organization: put 'actions' into nested type to reduce/group entry points?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I've read about different ways to organize graphql queries. 
Most seem to show a query/mutation for each different action.

i.e.

```js
@Query('getComment')
async getComment() {
  ...
  return comment;
}
@Query('getComments')
async getComments() {
  ...
  return comments;
}
@Query('getCommentByID')
async getCommentById(id) {
  ...
  return comment;
}
```

After adding all the different permutations, I have a lot of queries and mutations.

Other sources suggest to keep entry points to the graph minimal. 
After some experimentation I have:

```js
// schema
type Query {
  comment: CommentActions
}

type CommentActions {
  getCommentByID(id: ID!): Comment
  getAllComments(): [Comment]
  getComments(): [Comment]
    ...
    // etc
}
```

then in my resolver (this example in NestJS/apollo)

```js
@Query('comment')
async getComment(): Promise < CommentActions > {
  return new CommentActions();
}

@ResolveProperty('getAllComments')
async getAllComments(@Parent() comment) {
  // ...
  return comments;
}

@ResolveProperty('getCommentById')
async getAllComments(@Parent() comment, @Args('id')) {
  // ...
  return comment;
}
// etc
```

Query variations are essentially moved to field resolvers. This POC works fine technically (querying the graph without issue).

A query example looks like:

```js
query {
   comment {
    getAllComments {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I like this because it means in the published graph schema (e.g in gql playground), things can be grouped more easily, and each entity only has a single entry point.

Are there flaws to this approach? 
Is it 'ok' but not a very 'graphql' way to do things: I worry I'm inadvertently forcing a REST like model where it doesn't fit.

Are there issues or other tasks which will become much more difficult and/or impossible as schema gets more complex?

Any/all feedback, insight or suggestions for alternative structure greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Are mutation methods required to be on the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459947/are-mutation-methods-required-to-be-on-the-top-level)

Comment: thank you very much, i will read it through

Comment: so @daniel would you consider this grouping approach to be OK for queries, but not for mutations (per your linked comments), or you suggest keeping everything at root?

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to respond

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195422/discussion-between-daniel-rearden-and-baku).

Comment: @Daniel Rearden , It's a good discussion. In conclusion, It's anti-pattern, but has no side effect, Is it right?